# access-control-allow-origin (CORS) Amazon CloudFront

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to set up Amazon CloudFront that it works well.
Everything works fine, exept for `access-control-allow-origin "*"`

I added inside my .htaccess file the following:

```
 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch \.(eot|ttf|otf|svg|tif|tiff|woff)$>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </FilesMatch>
 </ifModule>
```

And checking the file direclty on the server, it works fine:

```
curl -I https://domain.com/fonts/font.woff
```

I get the result `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

But when I check it for the Amazon CloudFront url, it does not work. It is not added to the header.

I also added the "Origin" to the whitelist, see:

[image]

But it still does not work, it is not added to the header.

**EDIT:**

When I create a new .woff file and load it over CloudFront `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is still not edit. So I still miss something, what am I missing?

See my header:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 23 Dec 2016 08:05:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10886400; includeSubDomains; preload
Location: https://domain.com/fonts/font_2.woff
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Sun, 22 Jan 2017 08:05:32 GMT
Age: 21
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 9635c619f121d7a236fe1312f20e5f1b.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: Ygkldos5hh6s5AwolxfL5nzoxsNJPl-vpmeoNZ8fEGSKPVCgzbIFtg==
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT 2:**

Looks like it is because of my current https redirect in .htaccess. See:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It read in cache maybe. If you can restart your IIS it can be fixed or wait.

Comment: Thanks, how can I restart ISS?

Comment: Connect your server by remote and start IIS manager, select your web page .click restart. you can look this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324090

Comment: Hi, I create a new .woff file and load it over CloudFront Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is still not edit. So I still miss something, what am I missing?

Comment: Could you check .htaccess file's read/write permissions? On the other hand this woff file should be exist in your server. In windows server in this folder path: C:\Windows\Fonts

Comment: Otherwise you can check your requests method with this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: Thanks! The problem seems to be in the 301 redirect. For some reason CloudFront 301 redirect the file to my orginal file on the server. But when I check the orginal file with curl, I get a 200 OK result. Check the same file on CloudFront I get the 301. Why is it redirecting?

Comment: Hi, see my second edit. It looks like it is because of my current redirect. How can I solve this? What should I need to change?

Comment: try this                                                                                        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]